# Updating specific attribute for a specific user

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am trying to update a specific attribute for a specific user in mongodb. I am having trouble understanding the nested-ness. Any help would be appreciated.

My specific problem is that I want to update a the activeID for a specific _cID that is specific to a User(a user can have many _cID's hence the array type in settings.

Here is the server call that I currently have

```
    'updateActive' : function (p_id, c_id) {
    Collections.Users.update({_id: Meteor.userId(), _cID: c_id},{$set: {'settings.$.activeID': p_id}});
    }
```

and the schema

```
Schemas.CSettings = new SimpleSchema({
  _id: {
    type: String
  },
  _cID: {
    type: String
  },

  activeID: {
    type: String,
    optional: true
  }
});

Schemas.User = new SimpleSchema({
  _id: {
    type: String
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date
  },
  profile: {
    type: Schemas.UserProfile
  },

  settings: {
    type: [Schemas.CSettings],
    optional: true
  }
});
```

Comment: you need the positional operator: 'settings.$.activeID' as described here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/

Comment: Is this on the client or the server?

Comment: This is on the server

Comment: If you have the answer then put it in the answer box and accept it. PS: You can use SimpleSchema.RegEx.Id for an ID field.

Comment: I do not have the answer. Asya pointed me in the right direction.